Do solutions to the time-independent Schrödinger equation always (for any $V$) form a basis for solutions to the time-dependent equation?
Griffith's "Intro to Quantum Mechanics" shows that for $V(x)=x^2$ and $V(x)=0$, solutions to the SE can be constructed as a linear combination of stationary solutions. But is there a theorem that this is possible for any $V(x)$? (i.e. that for any $V(x)$, the stationary solutions form a basis for the space of all solutions). The book doesn't prove it afaict.

If $V$ is such that $H=T+V$ is self-adjoint, then this follows from the spectral theorem (a mathematical result of functional analysis).

The above should be a short and sweet answer to this question.

@MattHanson, actually it should probably also say how it follows from the spectral theorem.

@user56834 What do you mean "how it follows"? This IS (part of) the spectral theorem.

@TobiasFünke, I mean, how does one use the spectral theorem to prove this result. I don't think it's AS trivial as saying "apply the spectral theorem", if one wants to be very rigorous.

@TobiasFünke For one, afaict, the spectral theorem can be used to show that the eigenvectors of $H$ form a basis to represent any $\psi(x)$ in, but doesn't directly show the analogous for $\Psi(x,t)$.

? If you prove that the Hamiltonian is self-adjoint, then the spectral theorem applies, which in particular says it admits an orthonormal eigenbasis. To be rigorous, of course you have to take care what self-adjoint means in a mathematical sense: often physicist mean what a mathematician would call symmetric or hermitian (two notions which might also differ in the literature). And then ONB does not necessarily mean a ONB in the Hilbert space sense, but in a generalized sense. There, too, one has to formulate this precisely (else it is undefined or wrong), ut for most physicist, this is fine.

Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. $\psi(t)=U(t)\psi$ solves the TDSE to the initial condition $\psi(0)=\psi$... $U$ is bounded and hence you can interchange operator and series/sum... I can just re-iterate: If you want a mathematical precise version, read a mathematical physics/functional analysis/math of QM book. Everything can be made rigorous, but this is rarely done in any physics QM course, because there are many subtleties, especially with "generalized" orthonormal bases and so on. If you want to ask questions about mathematical rigour, make it more explicit!

@TobiasFünke, do you know the term "curse of knowledge"? (The curse of knowledge is a cognitive bias that occurs when an individual, who is communicating with others, assumes that others have information that is only available to themselves, assuming they all share a background and understanding.) I'm asking this question because I LITERALLY don't see how to prove the end result. I am just looking for a simple (but exact and not handwavy) proof.

spectral theorem says (basically): (#) some subset of the eigenvectors of hermitian operator $H$ on hilbert space $S$ form an orthonormal basis of $S$. A stationary solution to the schroedinger equation satisfies $\Psi(x,t)=\psi(x)\phi(t)$, with $H\psi=E\psi$. Therefore the eigenvectors of $H$ are the stationary solutions. We know from (#) that the eigenvectors form a basis for time-independent $\psi$, but not that $\psi\phi$ forms a basis for all $\Psi(x,t)$.

My last comment: The spectral theorem is very complicated and needs a lot of pre-knowledge. An easier version can be understood in terms of linear algebra, namely in the case of finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces. I don't know what else to say. Either you accept it (and possibly study the finite-dim. case) and work on the level of rigor your textbook/course does, or you take a more sophisticated book, possibly a math of QM book, and study it. Regarding your last comment: I honestly don't understand what you mean. $\psi(x,t)$ is always expressible in an ONB, specifically the eigenbasis of $H$.

@TobiasFünke, I am just asking for an exact explanation. I suggest to stop this discussion (and also the discussion to my other questions).
